# Почему не работает beforeEach во Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Стандартная ситуация предоставления права доступа к личному кабинету пользователя только при успешной авторизации юзера:

1. есть рабочее глобальное хранилище Vuex, хранящее флаг авторизован пользователь или нет
2. флаг можно просмотреть через геттер

Вот настройка объектов маршрутов:

```
var routes = [
{    
    name: 'a',
    path: '/',
    component: Start
},
{
    name: 'b',
    path: '/signup', alias: '/sign',
    component: SignUp
},
{
    name: 'c',
    path: '/user',
    component: User,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth : true
    }
},
{
    name: 'd',
    path: '*',
    component: NotFound
}
```

]

А здесь представлен хук на инициализацию каждого маршрута:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
  if (store.getters.getStateUser) {
    next({
      path: '/sign',
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath,
      },
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
} else {
  next();
}
```

})

На разных этапах проверяю флаг авторизации через:
`console.log(store.getters.getStateUser)`
но роутеру плевать на то, что он стоит в FALSE, он всеравно дает переход в приватный компонент User

Comment: А если в next передать false в тех случаях, когда мы не хотим дальше идти?

Comment: А если он стоит true - куда переходит, в sign?

Comment: @AlexSazonov, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Дмытрык, кто стоит?

Comment: Сложно сказать, я повторил Вашу логику - у меня все работает. Думаю, что дело во флаге